# I'm going to kill the trivia tag. Any objections?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [trivia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) tag is stupid.

It adds *no value* to the questions it is on. It is a meta tag, describing the question moreso than the information in the question, which is frowned upon. Questions that are *about* trivia are generally not *about* gaming and are thus of questionable nature on this site anyway. Trivia is at best something that should be included as a fun addendum to an answer about something else, and not something that should be the primary focus of a question on this site.

I'm going to slowly kill it off unless I hear any objections by around noon tomorrow.

Sound good?

Comment: Has the `trivia` tag murdered your firstborn child? Why such animosity? O_o

Comment: @RavenDreamer It doesn't add any useful information as a tag. Most things that are *about* trivia don't belong on the site.

Comment: You're right that it is a meta tag.

Comment: Well, I'm glad that at least my question did something good.

Comment: +1 for correct usage of the term "meta tag"

Comment: Someone completed, the official status image should be edited in- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121570/i-made-us-some-trogdor-graphics

Comment: Mods should have a [status:burninated] tag

Comment: We need to blacklist it. Otherwise it's just going to [keep coming back](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/2116/revisions).

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro ehhh...what if a game is legitimately called Trivia? Blacklist just breaks stuff. That was probably a good-faith mistake

Comment: @Ben Brocka: Argh.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

Answer (score 21):

None whatsoever.  [murder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder) away!!